# The given sign-in provider is disabled for this Firebase project. while try phone base login

Tags: firebase, angularfire

```
I have enable firebase phone auth , and try to login from web platform , facing below issues.
```

** It also failed to load identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:sendVerificationCode?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:1
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ().**

```
Firebase: The given sign-in provider is disabled for this Firebase project. Enable it in the Firebase console, under the sign-in method tab of the Auth section. (auth/operation-not-allowed).
    
    Firebase: The given sign-in provider is disabled for this Firebase project. Enable it in the Firebase console, under the sign-in method tab of the Auth section. (auth/operation-not-allowed).
    ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): SMS not sent
```